# Conflicts between Autowired and Validated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have been looking for a few days, issues related to a conflict that may be occurring or a wrong configuration I made when putting the spring boot into the project.

All dependencies are normally injected (@Autowired) when the (@Validated) is not present in the code, so it is inserted, everything stops being injected by the spring.

**gradle.properties**

```
SPRING_BOOT_VERSION=2.0.3.RELEASE
SPRING_CLOUD_VERSION=Finchley.RELEASE
```

I tried the version:

```
SPRING_BOOT_VERSION=2.1.0.M2
```

**dependencies build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = SPRING_BOOT_VERSION
        springCloudVersion = SPRING_CLOUD_VERSION
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}",
            "org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:3.2.1"
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop",
        "org.springframework:spring-context",
        "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.0",
        "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.0"

    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-alpn-conscrypt-server",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.http2:http2-server",
        "org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:3.2.1",
        "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15",
        "org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.1"

    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0"

    runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34"
}
```

**Application.java**

```
package br.com.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 * Spring Boot Application class
 */
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "br.com.app.*")
public class Application {

    /**
     * Spring boot application main
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package br.com.app.entrypoints.rest;

import br.com.app.user.usecases.CreateUser;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Api(value = "/user", tags = "User")
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/user",
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
@Validated
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class UserController {

    private final CreateUser createUser;

    @PostMapping(value = "/create")
    public final ResponseEntity<Response> createUser(@RequestHeader("token") final String token, @RequestBody final Request request) {
        return createUser.execute( ... ); // createUser is null
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:215) ~[websocket-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) ~[jetty-security-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:724) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260) [jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281) [jetty-io-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102) [jetty-io-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118) [jetty-io-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762) [jetty-util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680) [jetty-util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at br.com.app.entrypoints.rest.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

These are some links that I used as a reference:

https://coderanch.com/t/602044/java/Autowiring-work-custom-constraint-validator

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-property-validation

https://memorynotfound.com/custom-password-constraint-validator-annotation

Tks for help

Comment: I think questions on this StackOverflow version should be asked in english only (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange and https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/). Nevertheless there is a portugese version: Português StackOverflow: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: could you show the console error?

Comment: I activated Debug and added log to post.

The complete code: [github.com](https://github.com/dmends/poc)

Comment: i think you should autowire field `createUser`

Comment: Remove final from your method signature and it will work.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks for the help M. Deinum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that, by defining a method *final* the class designer promises this method will always work as described, or implied. But validations need to create a partial customization that is only possible without the *final*.

changing from:

```
public final ResponseEntity<Response> createUser(@RequestHeader("token") final String token, @RequestBody final Request request) {
    return createUser.execute( ... ); // createUser is null
}
```

for

```
public ResponseEntity<Response> createUser(@RequestHeader("token") final String token, @RequestBody final Request request) {
    return createUser.execute( ... ); // createUser is null
}
```